# Aggregating postgres union results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get a singel result row per date in SQL, using a single table in a postgres DB. I tried using Union, but I think this is not the right way. Can somone help me construct the right SQL.

Sample Data Columns for Table content: id,creationdate,contenttype

```
1 |2016-04-02|PAGE
2 |2016-04-02|ATTACHMENT
3 |2016-04-02|PAGE
4 |2016-04-03|ATTACHMENT
5 |2016-04-03|PAGE
6 |2016-04-03|ATTACHMENT
7 |2016-04-03|PAGE
8 |2016-04-04|ATTACHMENT
9 |2016-04-04|ATTACHMENT
10|2016-04-04|ATTACHMENT
```

If Use this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  date(creationdate) AS create_date,
  COUNT(*) AS PAGE,0 AS ATTACHMENT 
FROM 
  content 
WHERE 
  contenttype='PAGE' GROUP BY content.creationdate 
UNION
SELECT 
  date(creationdate) AS create_date,
  0 AS PAGE,COUNT(*) AS ATTACHMENT
FROM 
  content 
WHERE 
  contenttype='ATTACHMENT' GROUP BY content.creationdate 
ORDER BY create_date ASC;
```

I get the result

```
|create_date|PAGE|ATTACHMENT|
|2016-04-02|0|2|
|2016-04-02|1|0|
|2016-04-03|0|2|
|2016-04-03|1|0|
|2016-04-04|3|0|
```

What I want is:

```
|create_date|PAGE|ATTACHMENT|
|2016-04-02|1|2|
|2016-04-03|2|2|
|2016-04-04|3|0|
```

Comment: And what is the result you expect?

Comment: You want to remove those duplicates?

Comment: What I am looking for is a aggrigates singel result per date, so instead of having two entries for ie: 2016-04-02 in my results, I would like a single result with both counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation by selecting from the table only once:

```
SELECT date(creationdate) AS create_date,
       count(CASE WHEN contenttype='PAGE' then 1 end) as PAGE,
       count(CASE WHEN contenttype='ATTACHMENT' then 1 end) as ATTACHMENT
FROM 
  content 
GROUP BY content.creationdate 
ORDER BY create_date ASC;
```

Comment: with a current Postgres version you can also use a filtered aggregate: e.g. `count(*) filter (where contenttype = 'PAGE')`

Comment: Yes (except that `false` is something different then `0`, this is not MySQL) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Comment: I can't really see the advantage of count, other than you can't send a else as @dnoeth did with sum. The value of the case/then is also really irrelevant.

Comment: @WillemP.Botha The count is exactly the same as sum, unless you want to sum something. But your requirments were counting. No need for an else clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need a *conditional aggregate*:

```
SELECT 
  date(creationdate) AS create_date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN contenttype='PAGE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PAGE,
  SUM(CASE WHEN contenttype='ATTACHMENT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ATTACHMENT
FROM 
  content 
GROUP BY content.creationdate 
ORDER BY create_date ASC;
```

Comment: if the sample data contains another value other than PAGE and ATTACHMENT one get's empty entries again. Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: @WillemP.Botha: What do you mean by *empty entries*, rows where both `PAGE` and `ATTACHMENT` are zero? You can either add a `WHERE`-condition to remove other values before aggregation or add another `SUM(CASE...)`.

Comment: I added a SUM(CASE) for all values, but I guess I could have done the WHERE CLAUSE to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

several ways:

```
SELECT   date(c.creationdate) AS create_date,
p p_count,a_count 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT creationdate FROM content) c INNER JOIN (SELECT  creationdate,count() p_count FROM CONTENT GROUP
BY creationdate,contenttype   HAVING contenttype='PAGE') p on p.creationdate=c.creationdate
INNER JOIN (SELECT  creationdate,count() a_count FROM CONTENT GROUP
BY creationdate,contenttype   HAVING contenttype='ATTACHMENT') p
ON p.creationdate=c.creationdate ORDER BY c.creationdate
```

one is this

Comment: What the hell did you do here?

Comment: another way...  most general

Comment: this sql really hurts my head

Comment: Your query was tricky and applicable only in this special case. I don't want make the superhero, I didn't think at this solution. But if you read the questions about the SQL in stack exchange, you are going to notice that mostly of them are about problems with aggregating functions. So I leave this comment to show that when you have to deal with aggregating functions in complex queries,  the right way is to use sub-queries, than may be you can use such tricks to improve your query.